# GLSL Fragment shader UV displacement based on world space

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I'm trying to create an rgb offset effect for images on a website. I have the basic functionality but the problem is the channels are offset with the uv of the texture. So if images are different sizes the offset is not visually the same for each image.

This is my fragment shader.

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
varying vec2 vUv; // vertex uv


void main() {
    vec2 uv = vUv;

    float red = texture2D(texture, vec2(uv.x, uv.y - .1)).r;
    float green = texture2D(texture, uv).g;
    float blue = texture2D(texture, vec2(uv.x, uv.y + .1)).b;
    float alpha = texture2D(texture, uv).a;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(red, green, blue), alpha);

}
```

And how it looks rendered to the page.

[image: example]

How would I go about normalising the uv offset without having to pass in a uniform value?

Comment: Why not using an additional uniform? It should be easy to solve this issue with a `vec2` uniform that represents the resolution of your image.

Comment: I could if that's the only way to do it, I was wondering if there was anyway to do this without using any additional uniforms? I'm still trying to get the hold of shaders.

Comment: Passing in uniforms is the normal and arguably smart thing to do. Especially for this case. Passing in the texture resolution is probably the wrong solution though. No reason to hard code something that doesn't need to be hard coded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be normal to pass in more info like the amount of offset

```
uniform float offset1;
uniform float offset2;
uniform sampler2D texture;
varying vec2 vUv; // vertex uv


void main() {
    vec2 uv = vUv;

    float red = texture2D(texture, vec2(uv.x, uv.y + offset1)).r;
    float green = texture2D(texture, uv).g;
    float blue = texture2D(texture, vec2(uv.x, uv.y + offset2)).b;
    float alpha = texture2D(texture, uv).a;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(red, green, blue), alpha);

}
```

You can then adjust this in JavaScript. For example

```
  const uniforms = {
    offset1:  { value: 0 },
    offset2:  { value: 0 },
    ...
  };

  ...

  uniforms.offset1.value =  2 / textureHeight;
  uniforms.offset2.value = -2 / textureHeight;
```

If it was me I might do it more like this

```
uniform vec2 channelOffsets[4];
uniform vec4 channelMult[4];
uniform sampler2D texture;
varying vec2 vUv; // vertex uv


void main() {
    vec2 uv = vUv;

    vec4 channel0 = texture2D(texture, uv + channelOffset[0]);
    vec4 channel1 = texture2D(texture, uv + channelOffset[1]);
    vec4 channel2 = texture2D(texture, uv + channelOffset[2]);
    vec4 channel3 = texture2D(texture, uv + channelOffset[3]);

    gl_FragColor = 
        channelMult[0] * channel0 +
        channelMult[1] * channel1 +
        channelMult[2] * channel2 +
        channelMult[3] * channel3 ; 
}
```

And set them

```
  const uniforms = {
    channelOffsets:  { value: [
      new THREE.Vector2(),
      new THREE.Vector2(),
      new THREE.Vector2(),
      new THREE.Vector2(),
    ]},
    channelMults: { value: [
      new THREE.Vector4(1, 0, 0, 0),
      new THREE.Vector4(0, 1, 0, 0),
      new THREE.Vector4(0, 0, 1, 0),
      new THREE.Vector4(0, 0, 0, 1),
    ]},
    ....
  }

...

  uniforms.channelOffsets.value[0].y = -2 / textureHeight;
  uniforms.channelOffsets.value[2].y =  2 / textureHeight;
```

For an example of something less hard coded. I might even use texture matrices instead of offsets which would allow rotating and scaling each channel and combine them with matrices which would allow swapping channels.

Answer (score 3):

If you would use a [WebGL 2.0](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/)  context (see [How to use WebGL2](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-use-WebGL2)), then you can use [`textureSize`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.1/html/textureSize.xhtml) to get the sizeof the texture. e.g.:

```c
#version 300 es

uniform sampler2D tex;
in      vec2      vUv;
out     vec4      color;

void main() {
    vec2 uv = vUv;

    vec2  size   = vec2(textureSize(tex, 0));
    float pixel  = 10.0;
    float offset = pixel / size.y;

    float red   = texture(tex, vec2(uv.x, uv.y - offset)).r;
    float green = texture(tex, uv).g;
    float blue  = texture(tex, vec2(uv.x, uv.y + offset)).b;
    float alpha = texture(tex, uv).a;

    color = vec4(red, green, blue, alpha);
}
```

Note, you've to change the name of the texture sampler uniform

Comment: This would be perfect if I didn't have to support IE

Answer (score 3):

If you need to know which pixel you're on in *screen-space* (not 3D world space), you can use `gl_FragCoord`. For example, in a 1080p display, `gl_FragCoord.x` will start at 0 on the left, and increase to 1920 on the right of your screen. `gl_FragCoord.y` will have a range a bit shorter than [0, 1080] (due to the OS menu bars). You can extract these coordinates in your fragment shader like this:

```
vec2 coord = gl_FragCoord.xy;
```

That way you'll know which pixel you're on in screen-space, without having to pass in another uniform. See here for more details:

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml

Comment: But how would that help with applying an offset on the uv? If I understand correctly the UV goes from -1 to 1. I can't apply an offset in pixels directly to the uv, I'd have to calculate the size of the texture compared to the gl_FragCoord, but I don't believe I have the texture size without passing in a uniform (unless using webgl 2 like stated in an answer above).